# Installshield fails to stop and delete windows service during uninstall

Tags: installshield

I have an msi project that installs 2 windows services.  I have `Uninstall Stop = Yes` and `Uninstall Delete = Yes`, but when I uninstall the application, the services do not stop or delete.  This worked at one point and recently started failing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem with InstallShield 2010 premier

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  Can you open up your MSI in Orca or Direct Edit mode in Installshield and look at the ServiceControl table?  It should have an "event" bitfield that tells you when it should stop/start/install/remove services.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Wait Type = Wait For event to complete`.

Also please kill or terminate the dependent applications of EXEs before Uninstall Service action.